# Use custom field checkbox in admin product page - PrestaShop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-1.5

I have a custom field (checkbox) in the product admin page:

Informations.tpl:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <span class="pull-right">{include file="controllers/products/multishop/checkbox.tpl" field="is_exclusive" type="checkbox" multilang="false"}</span></div>
    <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="is_exclusive">
        <span class="label-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{l s='Is Exclusive'}">
            {l s='Is Exclusive ?'}
        </span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <input class="admin-form-check form-control" type="checkbox" id="is_exclusive" name="is_exclusive" value="1" {if $product->is_exclusive}checked{/if}/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And have added it to `override/classes/Product.php`:

```
public $is_exclusive = false;
    function __construct( $id_product = null, $full = false, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null, Context $context = null ) {
         Product::$definition['fields']['is_exclusive'] = 
                array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'lang' => false, 'validate' => 'isBool');
```

I need a way to catch when the checkbox is unchecked and assign the field with 0.

I have created `override/controllers/admin/AdminProductsController.php`:

```
class AdminProductsController extends AdminProductsControllerCore {
    protected function copyFromPost(&$object, $table) {
        if ( $this->isTabSubmitted( 'Informations' ) ) {
            if ( $this->checkMultishopBox( 'is_exclusive', $this->context ) ) {
                $object->is_exclusive = (int) Tools::getValue( 'is_exclusive' );
            }

        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to delete cache file: `cache/class_index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in Prestashopp 1.6 => The solution is to delete cache file: `cache/class_index.php`
In prestashop 1.7 => The solution is to delete cache file: `var/cache/class_index.php`

Regards